# SPD 2013 Workflow Subtask

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks

Is there a way to create a workflow that automatically assigns a task as a subtask of another task.

For example form is submitted, start work flow that creates main task, then creates 3 subtask for main task.